# ReactiveX Operator to be notified when n items have been emitted or interval elapsed whichever comes first

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an observable emitting items and I want to be notified when n items have been emitted or a certain time interval has elapsed. I am looking for the Reactive operator that would let me do that.

This operator could have the same signature that Buffer(timeSpan, count) has. I could even use Buffer except that I don't want to buffer anything, I just need the event that says:

> n items emitted or interval elapsed

.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on this problem:

```
/// <summary>Returns true if the specified number of elements have been emitted
/// before the timeout has elapsed; otherwise, false.</summary>
public static IObservable<bool> EmittedCountOrTimeout<T>(
    this IObservable<T> source, int count, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    return source
        .Take(count)     // Take the first 'count' elements
        .Count()         // Count the number of emitted elements
        .Contains(count) // Confirm that 'count' elements have been emitted (could be less)
        .Timeout(timeout, Observable.Return(false)); // On timeout return false
}
```